# gson.fromJson when json object is inconsistent with java object

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Assume I have a class:

```
class A {
    List<C> b;
}

class C {
    String str;
}
```

And I have a json string which contains the following:

```
{ 
    "b": [ 
        { ... },
        { ... }
     ]
}
```

So doing the following will work just fine:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(jsonString, A.class);
```

But now  I have a more complex case, where Im using the same json to deliver more data, but I still want to use gson, as its very nice library.
So now my json is as follows:

```
{ 
    "b": [ 
        { ... },
        { ... }
     ],
    "c": 7
}
```

Is it possible to tell gson object to ignore what it cant evaluate? 
So It will take only what it knows from my `A` class, or what I specified using `@SerializedName` ?

Im aware of the more primitive way, using `JSONObject`, but for keep using `Gson` I will have to make `"b"` nested in one more level for it to work, as it requires an object with an array of objects, and using `JSONObject.get("b")` will give me only the array within.

**UPDATE, to be more specific, I add a json object which I try to work with**

This json is what I started with, just an array of `b`'s, which works fine if I run it:

```
{
        "b": [
            {
                "str": "first string"
            }
        ]
}
```

This json is a more complex case where I do have a list of `b`'s, which is exactly as gson needs, but also another parameter which isnt specific for my `A` class, which is what I want gson to ignore and behave like the first case.

```
{
    "b": [
        {
            "str": "first string"
        }
    ],
    "c": 7
}
```

Comment: Can yous post the exact Json string for that you want to use GSON?Even for complex Json, GSON can be applicable.

Comment: so what are you getting problem? don't know which part of Json you are saying complex

Answer (score 0):

The way we was always fixing this kind of problem was defining placeholder class, that was able to grab the data, so:

```
class A {
    List<C> b;
}

class C {
    String str;
}

class ContainerA extends HashMap<String, A>{
}
```

Then you do:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, A> javaMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ContainerA.class);
```

This is sort of workaround, but works OK for Gson and Spring for Android with `GsonHttpMessageConverter`.